# Huawei E3372 not working after unplug/reattach

Tags: networking, usb-modem

I am using a Huawei E3372 LTE modem under Ubuntu 17.04.

```
/eth/network/interfaces

allow-hotplug wwx001e101f0000
iface wwx001e101f0000 inet dhcp
    pre-up /bin/echo -e "AT^NDISDUP=1,1,\"internet\"\r" > /dev/ttyUSB0  
    post-down /bin/echo -ne 'AT^NDISDUP=1,0\r\n' > /dev/ttyUSB
```

It works if:

1. I leave USB plugged in and I do a restart
2. I plug first time to
   the machine

Log for this case:

```
    Jul 24 22:50:06 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  143.152401] random: crng init done
Jul 24 22:50:08 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  145.092450] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
Jul 24 22:50:08 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  145.240887] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=14fe
Jul 24 22:50:08 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  145.240890] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jul 24 22:50:08 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  145.240891] usb 1-2: Product: HUAWEI_MOBILE
Jul 24 22:50:08 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  145.240892] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: HUAWEI_MOBILE
Jul 24 22:50:08 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  145.240893] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 0123456789ABCDEF
Jul 24 22:50:08 ubuntu-linux systemd[1]: Created slice system-usb_modeswitch.slice.
Jul 24 22:50:08 ubuntu-linux systemd[1]: Starting USB_ModeSwitch_1-2:1.0...
Jul 24 22:50:08 ubuntu-linux usb_modeswitch_dispatcher[1405]: Could not read attribute: No such file or directory
Jul 24 22:50:08 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  145.432751] usb-storage 1-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Jul 24 22:50:08 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  145.432874] scsi host8: usb-storage 1-2:1.0
Jul 24 22:50:08 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  145.433024] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
Jul 24 22:50:08 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  145.438274] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
Jul 24 22:50:09 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  146.461913] scsi 8:0:0:0: CD-ROM            HUAWEI   Mass Storage     2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
Jul 24 22:50:09 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  146.466068] scsi 8:0:0:1: Direct-Access     HUAWEI   TF CARD Storage  2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
Jul 24 22:50:08 ubuntu-linux usb_modeswitch_dispatcher[1405]: message repeated 2 times: [ Could not read attribute: No such file or directory]
Jul 24 22:50:09 ubuntu-linux usb_modeswitch: switch device 12d1:14fe on 001/003
Jul 24 22:50:09 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  146.512229] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr1] scsi-1 drive
Jul 24 22:50:09 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  146.512465] sr 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr1
Jul 24 22:50:09 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  146.512562] sr 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 5
Jul 24 22:50:09 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  146.512784] sd 8:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
Jul 24 22:50:09 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  146.550305] sd 8:0:0:1: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
Jul 24 22:50:09 ubuntu-linux systemd-udevd[1435]: Process '/lib/udev/hdparm' failed with exit code 2.
Jul 24 22:50:09 ubuntu-linux systemd-udevd[1435]: inotify_add_watch(9, /dev/sdb, 10) failed: No such file or directory
Jul 24 22:50:09 ubuntu-linux systemd-udevd[1429]: inotify_add_watch(9, /dev/sdb, 10) failed: No such file or directory
Jul 24 22:50:09 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  146.786589] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 3
Jul 24 22:50:11 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  147.896712] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
Jul 24 22:50:11 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  148.045492] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=1506
Jul 24 22:50:11 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  148.045495] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Jul 24 22:50:11 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  148.045497] usb 1-2: Product: HUAWEI_MOBILE
Jul 24 22:50:11 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  148.045498] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: HUAWEI_MOBILE
Jul 24 22:50:11 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  148.684183] usb-storage 1-2:1.3: USB Mass Storage device detected
Jul 24 22:50:11 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  148.684397] scsi host8: usb-storage 1-2:1.3
Jul 24 22:50:11 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  148.685635] usb-storage 1-2:1.4: USB Mass Storage device detected
Jul 24 22:50:11 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  148.685737] scsi host9: usb-storage 1-2:1.4
Jul 24 22:50:11 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  148.703822] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial
Jul 24 22:50:11 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  148.703834] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
Jul 24 22:50:11 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  148.703845] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic
Jul 24 22:50:11 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  148.714421] usbcore: registered new interface driver option
Jul 24 22:50:11 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  148.714437] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for GSM modem (1-port)
Jul 24 22:50:11 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  148.714507] option 1-2:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
Jul 24 22:50:11 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  148.716110] usb 1-2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
Jul 24 22:50:11 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  148.716137] option 1-2:1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
Jul 24 22:50:11 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  148.716270] usb 1-2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
Jul 24 22:50:11 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  148.717436] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ncm
Jul 24 22:50:11 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  148.720558] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_wdm
Jul 24 22:50:11 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  148.819152] huawei_cdc_ncm 1-2:1.2: MAC-Address: 00:1e:10:1f:00:00
Jul 24 22:50:11 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  148.819156] huawei_cdc_ncm 1-2:1.2: setting rx_max = 16384
Jul 24 22:50:11 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  148.827157] huawei_cdc_ncm 1-2:1.2: NDP will be placed at end of frame for this device.
Jul 24 22:50:11 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  148.827378] huawei_cdc_ncm 1-2:1.2: cdc-wdm0: USB WDM device
Jul 24 22:50:11 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  148.827611] huawei_cdc_ncm 1-2:1.2 wwan0: register 'huawei_cdc_ncm' at usb-0000:00:1d.7-2, Huawei CDC NCM device, 00:1e:10:1f:00:00
Jul 24 22:50:11 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  148.827675] usbcore: registered new interface driver huawei_cdc_ncm
Jul 24 22:50:11 ubuntu-linux usb_modeswitch[1405]: usb_modeswitch: switched to 12d1:1506 on 1/4
Jul 24 22:50:11 ubuntu-linux usb_modeswitch_dispatcher[1405]: Could not read attribute: No such file or directory
Jul 24 22:50:11 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  148.831382] huawei_cdc_ncm 1-2:1.2 wwx001e101f0000: renamed from wwan0
Jul 24 22:50:12 ubuntu-linux systemd[1]: Found device Modem/Networkcard.
Jul 24 22:50:12 ubuntu-linux systemd[1]: Started ifup for wwx001e101f0000.
Jul 24 22:50:12 ubuntu-linux dhclient[1518]: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.5
Jul 24 22:50:12 ubuntu-linux sh[1500]: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.5
Jul 24 22:50:12 ubuntu-linux sh[1500]: Copyright 2004-2016 Internet Systems Consortium.
Jul 24 22:50:12 ubuntu-linux sh[1500]: All rights reserved.
Jul 24 22:50:12 ubuntu-linux sh[1500]: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Jul 24 22:50:12 ubuntu-linux dhclient[1518]: Copyright 2004-2016 Internet Systems Consortium.
Jul 24 22:50:12 ubuntu-linux dhclient[1518]: All rights reserved.
Jul 24 22:50:12 ubuntu-linux dhclient[1518]: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Jul 24 22:50:12 ubuntu-linux dhclient[1518]: 
Jul 24 22:50:12 ubuntu-linux dhclient[1518]: Listening on LPF/wwx001e101f0000/00:1e:10:1f:00:00
Jul 24 22:50:12 ubuntu-linux sh[1500]: Listening on LPF/wwx001e101f0000/00:1e:10:1f:00:00
Jul 24 22:50:12 ubuntu-linux sh[1500]: Sending on   LPF/wwx001e101f0000/00:1e:10:1f:00:00
Jul 24 22:50:12 ubuntu-linux sh[1500]: Sending on   Socket/fallback
Jul 24 22:50:12 ubuntu-linux sh[1500]: DHCPREQUEST of 100.64.119.246 on wwx001e101f0000 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x4a727742)
Jul 24 22:50:12 ubuntu-linux dhclient[1518]: Sending on   LPF/wwx001e101f0000/00:1e:10:1f:00:00
Jul 24 22:50:12 ubuntu-linux dhclient[1518]: Sending on   Socket/fallback
Jul 24 22:50:12 ubuntu-linux dhclient[1518]: DHCPREQUEST of 100.64.119.246 on wwx001e101f0000 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x4a727742)
Jul 24 22:50:12 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  149.720148] scsi 9:0:0:0: Direct-Access     HUAWEI   TF CARD Storage  2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
Jul 24 22:50:12 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  149.720637] scsi 8:0:0:0: CD-ROM            HUAWEI   Mass Storage     2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
Jul 24 22:50:12 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  149.720967] sd 9:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
Jul 24 22:50:12 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  149.729707] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr1] scsi-1 drive
Jul 24 22:50:12 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  149.729828] sr 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr1
Jul 24 22:50:12 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  149.729885] sr 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 5
Jul 24 22:50:12 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  149.731040] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
Jul 24 22:50:12 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  149.773904] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Jul 24 22:50:12 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  149.773907] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
Jul 24 22:50:12 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  149.773911] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
Jul 24 22:50:12 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  149.773913] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 8d fc 00 00 02 00
Jul 24 22:50:12 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  149.773915] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sr1, sector 145392
Jul 24 22:50:12 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  149.781680] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Jul 24 22:50:12 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  149.781682] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
Jul 24 22:50:12 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  149.781683] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
Jul 24 22:50:12 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  149.781685] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 8d fc 00 00 02 00
Jul 24 22:50:12 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  149.781686] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sr1, sector 145392
Jul 24 22:50:12 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  149.781727] Buffer I/O error on dev sr1, logical block 18174, async page read
Jul 24 22:50:12 ubuntu-linux usb_modeswitch_dispatcher[1405]: Unable to open bind list file: No such file or directory
Jul 24 22:50:12 ubuntu-linux usb_modeswitch[1405]: usb_modeswitch: add device ID 12d1:1506 to driver option
Jul 24 22:50:12 ubuntu-linux usb_modeswitch[1405]: usb_modeswitch: please report the device ID to the Linux USB developers!
Jul 24 22:50:13 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  149.932570] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Jul 24 22:50:13 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  149.932574] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
Jul 24 22:50:13 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  149.932576] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
Jul 24 22:50:13 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  149.932578] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 8c 80 00 00 3c 00
Jul 24 22:50:13 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  149.932580] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sr1, sector 143872
Jul 24 22:50:13 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  149.942133] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Jul 24 22:50:13 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  149.942136] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
Jul 24 22:50:13 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  149.942138] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
Jul 24 22:50:13 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  149.942140] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 8c 80 00 00 02 00
Jul 24 22:50:13 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  149.942142] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sr1, sector 143872
Jul 24 22:50:13 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  149.942184] Buffer I/O error on dev sr1, logical block 17984, async page read
Jul 24 22:50:13 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  149.975782] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Jul 24 22:50:13 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  149.975786] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
Jul 24 22:50:13 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  149.975787] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
Jul 24 22:50:13 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  149.975790] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 8d fa 00 00 02 00
Jul 24 22:50:13 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  149.975792] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sr1, sector 145384
Jul 24 22:50:13 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  149.985490] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Jul 24 22:50:13 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  149.985493] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
Jul 24 22:50:13 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  149.985495] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
Jul 24 22:50:13 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  149.985498] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 8d fa 00 00 02 00
Jul 24 22:50:13 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  149.985500] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sr1, sector 145384
Jul 24 22:50:13 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  149.985576] Buffer I/O error on dev sr1, logical block 18173, async page read
Jul 24 22:50:13 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  150.062111] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Jul 24 22:50:13 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  150.062114] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
Jul 24 22:50:13 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  150.062116] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
Jul 24 22:50:13 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  150.062117] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 8d f6 00 00 02 00
Jul 24 22:50:13 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  150.062119] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sr1, sector 145368
Jul 24 22:50:13 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  150.069790] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Jul 24 22:50:13 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  150.069796] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
Jul 24 22:50:13 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  150.069797] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
Jul 24 22:50:13 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  150.069799] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 8d f6 00 00 02 00
Jul 24 22:50:13 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  150.069801] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sr1, sector 145368
Jul 24 22:50:13 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  150.069842] Buffer I/O error on dev sr1, logical block 18171, async page read
Jul 24 22:50:13 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  150.102667] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Jul 24 22:50:13 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  150.102669] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
Jul 24 22:50:13 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  150.102671] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
Jul 24 22:50:13 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  150.102673] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 8c 80 00 00 3c 00
Jul 24 22:50:13 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  150.102674] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sr1, sector 143872
Jul 24 22:50:13 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  150.110487] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Jul 24 22:50:13 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  150.110489] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
Jul 24 22:50:13 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  150.110490] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
Jul 24 22:50:13 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  150.110492] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 8c 80 00 00 02 00
Jul 24 22:50:13 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  150.110494] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sr1, sector 143872
Jul 24 22:50:13 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  150.110537] Buffer I/O error on dev sr1, logical block 17984, async page read
Jul 24 22:50:13 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  150.127395] Buffer I/O error on dev sr1, logical block 18170, async page read
Jul 24 22:50:15 ubuntu-linux dhclient[1518]: DHCPREQUEST of 100.64.119.246 on wwx001e101f0000 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x4a727742)
Jul 24 22:50:15 ubuntu-linux sh[1500]: DHCPREQUEST of 100.64.119.246 on wwx001e101f0000 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x4a727742)
Jul 24 22:50:15 ubuntu-linux dhclient[1518]: DHCPNAK from 100.64.25.233 (xid=0x4277724a)
Jul 24 22:50:15 ubuntu-linux sh[1500]: DHCPNAK from 100.64.25.233 (xid=0x4277724a)
Jul 24 22:50:15 ubuntu-linux dhclient[1518]: DHCPDISCOVER on wwx001e101f0000 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x54674120)
Jul 24 22:50:15 ubuntu-linux sh[1500]: DHCPDISCOVER on wwx001e101f0000 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x54674120)
Jul 24 22:50:15 ubuntu-linux dhclient[1518]: DHCPREQUEST of 100.64.25.234 on wwx001e101f0000 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x20416754)
Jul 24 22:50:15 ubuntu-linux sh[1500]: DHCPREQUEST of 100.64.25.234 on wwx001e101f0000 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x20416754)
Jul 24 22:50:15 ubuntu-linux dhclient[1518]: DHCPOFFER of 100.64.25.234 from 100.64.25.233
Jul 24 22:50:15 ubuntu-linux sh[1500]: DHCPOFFER of 100.64.25.234 from 100.64.25.233
Jul 24 22:50:15 ubuntu-linux dhclient[1518]: DHCPACK of 100.64.25.234 from 100.64.25.233
Jul 24 22:50:15 ubuntu-linux sh[1500]: DHCPACK of 100.64.25.234 from 100.64.25.233
Jul 24 22:50:15 ubuntu-linux dhclient[1518]: bound to 100.64.25.234 -- renewal in 249600 seconds.
Jul 24 22:50:15 ubuntu-linux sh[1500]: bound to 100.64.25.234 -- renewal in 249600 seconds.
Jul 24 22:50:15 ubuntu-linux systemd[1]: Reloading OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Jul 24 22:50:15 ubuntu-linux systemd[1]: Reloaded OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Jul 24 22:50:15 ubuntu-linux systemd[1]: Reloading.
Jul 24 22:50:19 ubuntu-linux systemd[1]: Started USB_ModeSwitch_1-2:1.0.
```

ifconfig -a:

```
wwx001e101f0000: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 100.64.119.246  netmask 255.255.255.252  broadcast 100.64.119.247
        inet6 fe80::21e:10ff:fe1f:0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:1e:10:1f:00:00  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2  bytes 636 (636.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 24  bytes 2692 (2.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

However If I unplug for any reason and I reattach the modem it's stops working.

Now I am going to unplug and reattach the modem:

```
Jul 24 22:53:47 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  364.823156] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Jul 24 22:53:47 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  364.823176] WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 46 at /build/linux-Fk60NP/linux-4.10.0/drivers/usb/host/ehci-hcd.c:1053 ehci_endpoint_reset+0xfc/0x120
Jul 24 22:53:47 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  364.823176] clear_halt for a busy endpoint
Jul 24 22:53:47 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  364.823177] Modules linked in: huawei_cdc_ncm cdc_wdm cdc_ncm option usbnet usb_wwan mii usbserial uas usb_storage gpio_ich ppdev x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_intel8x0 coretemp snd_ac97_codec ac97_bus uvcvideo intel_rapl_perf videobuf2_vmalloc snd_pcm videobuf2_memops snd_timer videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_core input_leds snd videodev soundcore serio_raw media lpc_ich sbs shpchp pvpanic sbshc parport_pc parport mac_hid ib_iser rdma_cm iw_cm ib_cm ib_core configfs iscsi_tcp libiscsi_tcp libiscsi scsi_transport_iscsi ip_tables x_tables autofs4 btrfs raid10 raid456 async_raid6_recov async_memcpy async_pq async_xor async_tx xor raid6_pq libcrc32c raid1 raid0 multipath linear crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel pcbc aesni_intel aes_x86_64 crypto_simd glue_helper cryptd psmouse ahci libahci pata_acpi
Jul 24 22:53:47 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  364.823227]  virtio_net fjes
Jul 24 22:53:47 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  364.823233] CPU: 1 PID: 46 Comm: kworker/1:1 Not tainted 4.10.0-19-generic #21-Ubuntu
Jul 24 22:53:47 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  364.823234] Hardware name: Parallels Software International Inc. Parallels Virtual Platform/Parallels Virtual Platform, BIOS 12.1.1 (41491) 11/15/2016
Jul 24 22:53:47 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  364.823240] Workqueue: events usbnet_deferred_kevent [usbnet]
Jul 24 22:53:47 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  364.823242] Call Trace:
Jul 24 22:53:47 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  364.823252]  dump_stack+0x63/0x81
Jul 24 22:53:47 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  364.823256]  __warn+0xcb/0xf0
Jul 24 22:53:47 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  364.823257]  warn_slowpath_fmt+0x5f/0x80
Jul 24 22:53:47 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  364.823264]  ? usb_control_msg+0xec/0x120
Jul 24 22:53:47 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  364.823267]  ehci_endpoint_reset+0xfc/0x120
Jul 24 22:53:47 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  364.823269]  usb_hcd_reset_endpoint+0x25/0x60
Jul 24 22:53:47 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  364.823271]  usb_clear_halt+0x8b/0xb0
Jul 24 22:53:47 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  364.823274]  usbnet_deferred_kevent+0x10f/0x370 [usbnet]
Jul 24 22:53:47 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  364.823283]  ? __schedule+0x23b/0x6f0
Jul 24 22:53:47 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  364.823286]  process_one_work+0x1fc/0x4b0
Jul 24 22:53:47 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  364.823288]  worker_thread+0x4b/0x500
Jul 24 22:53:47 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  364.823293]  kthread+0x101/0x140
Jul 24 22:53:47 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  364.823294]  ? process_one_work+0x4b0/0x4b0
Jul 24 22:53:47 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  364.823297]  ? kthread_create_on_node+0x60/0x60
Jul 24 22:53:47 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  364.823301]  ret_from_fork+0x2c/0x40
Jul 24 22:53:47 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  364.823302] ---[ end trace a2439ebdff9d582d ]---
Jul 24 22:53:48 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  364.949036] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 4
Jul 24 22:53:48 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  364.949175] option1 ttyUSB0: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
Jul 24 22:53:48 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  364.949186] option 1-2:1.0: device disconnected
Jul 24 22:53:48 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  364.949256] option1 ttyUSB1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB1
Jul 24 22:53:48 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  364.949261] option 1-2:1.1: device disconnected
Jul 24 22:53:48 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  364.949297] huawei_cdc_ncm 1-2:1.2 wwx001e101f0000: unregister 'huawei_cdc_ncm' usb-0000:00:1d.7-2, Huawei CDC NCM device
Jul 24 22:53:48 ubuntu-linux dhclient[1599]: receive_packet failed on wwx001e101f0000: Network is down
Jul 24 22:53:48 ubuntu-linux systemd[1]: Stopping ifup for wwx001e101f0000...
Jul 24 22:53:48 ubuntu-linux systemd[1]: Reloading.
Jul 24 22:53:48 ubuntu-linux dhclient[1710]: Killed old client process
Jul 24 22:53:48 ubuntu-linux ifdown[1668]: Killed old client process
Jul 24 22:53:49 ubuntu-linux dhclient[1710]: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.5
Jul 24 22:53:49 ubuntu-linux ifdown[1668]: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.5
Jul 24 22:53:49 ubuntu-linux dhclient[1710]: Copyright 2004-2016 Internet Systems Consortium.
Jul 24 22:53:49 ubuntu-linux ifdown[1668]: Copyright 2004-2016 Internet Systems Consortium.
Jul 24 22:53:49 ubuntu-linux dhclient[1710]: All rights reserved.
Jul 24 22:53:49 ubuntu-linux ifdown[1668]: All rights reserved.
Jul 24 22:53:49 ubuntu-linux dhclient[1710]: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Jul 24 22:53:49 ubuntu-linux ifdown[1668]: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Jul 24 22:53:49 ubuntu-linux dhclient[1710]: 
Jul 24 22:53:49 ubuntu-linux dhclient[1710]: Error getting hardware address for "wwx001e101f0000": No such device
Jul 24 22:55:14 ubuntu-linux kernel: [  451.044516] Buffer I/O error on dev sr1, logical block 18170, async page read
Jul 24 22:55:20 ubuntu-linux systemd[1]: Started USB_ModeSwitch_1-2:1.0.
```

Comment: Are you properly "ejecting" the USB device before unplugging it? It looks like a USB flash drive. When you're unplugging it, it's crashing.

Comment: As I see it, it fails to mount as mass storage and then `USB_ModeSwitch` fails (hangs). It expects a known mass storage device PID in order to trigger the switch to modem mode.

Comment: Definitely this is the problem, because I simple unplug - connect it again. Interesting, that Linux can't handle this. Is there any workaround to this?